# Redirect to external url with parameters in django

Tags: python, django, redirect, post, httpresponse

I want when a user do something in my view then i redirect him to another website with some parameters as POST method Like when you submit a form.
I think its may be something like this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("url","parameters")
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't redirect with a `POST` method.  The only solution for this is to show intermediate html with a form and submit this form on `window.load` event:

```
return render(request, 'my_form.html', {'param1': 'Parameter 1',
                                        'param2': 'Parameter 2'})
```

And `my_form.html` will look like:

```
<html>
    <body onload="document.my_form.submit()">
        <form action="http://external_url" name="my_form" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="{{ param1 }}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="{{ param2 }}" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what i want

Comment: Another question, I need to send XML date with this form,How can i do that?

Comment: Just pass this data as `param1` value to the template.  AFAIK modern browsers support multiline value in the hidden input but for compatibility you have to escape `\n` and `\r` symbols. Or use `<textarea>` with `display: none` css property.

Comment: I think that value not has XML data type if server check the type. Is it correct?

Comment: XML is just a string.  I don't know anything about your server and how it validates the data.